# Make Python Program Wait

Tags: python

I need to make my python program wait for 200ms before polling for an input of some description. In C# for example, I could use `Thread.Sleep()` to achieve this. What is the simplest means of doing this in python?

Answer (score 29):

Use [Time](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) module.

For example, to delay 1 second :

```
import time
time.sleep(1) # delay for 1 seconds
```

In your case, if you want to get 200 ms, use this instead:

```
time.sleep(0.2)
```

time.sleep also works with float.

Answer (score 11):

If you simply want to sleep you can try:

```
import time

time.sleep(0.2)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the method `sleep()` in module `time`.

First you must import module `time` in your program.
After that, you can call the `sleep()` function.

Add this to your code:

```
import time
time.sleep(0.2)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [time library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) and use the command [time.sleep()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) to make it wait. It's more efficient when choosing to extract it from the [time library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) and then use just sleep()
For Example:

```
import time
print('hi')
time.sleep(0.2)
print('hello')
```

Improved:

```
from time import sleep
print('Loading...')
sleep(2)
print('Done!')
```

Note: it is measured in seconds not ms.

Comment: How is this any different from cnicutar's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15472727/369450), Thanakron Tandavas's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15472738/369450), or Zhong Xiaoqin's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15472840/369450)?

Comment: @cpburnz hey, you're being a little unfair suggesting that this answer isn't different from the others. The three answers you've linked to correctly use the `time.sleep()` function, which, like, *exists*, while this one uses the `time.wait()` function, which doesn't exist. Being completely incorrect counts as being different, right? Right?

Comment: @cpburnz I fear your sarcasm detector has failed, sir. I'm not seriously suggesting that this answer *gains* value by being wrong; I'm entirely on your side that it's garbage in need of deletion (though I can't place a delete vote until it gets another downvote).

Comment: @MarkAmery Sarcasm can be hard to detect in text especially when I'm sure I've seen people argue on Meta exactly that: any attempt to answer no matter how irrelevant or redundant should be kept because "it's _an_ answer".

Comment: Oops, I don't know what I was thinking!